# Solution to a differential equation that passes through a specific point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find the solution to the differential equation $\displaystyle\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{7 x y}{(\ln y)^{8}}$ through the point $(0,e)$. Express answer as $ln(y)=$

I'm not sure the steps for finding a solution through a specific point. I solved the differential equation like I would if it didn't ask to go through a specific point and got: $$y=(\frac{(63x)^2}{2}+C)^{\frac{1}{9}}$$. Not sure where to go from here. Do I just plug in $(0,e)$? I'm not sure how that would work, given the format I'm supposed to enter it in.

Comment: Yes your work is correct. Now plug in $(0, e)$ to find the value of $C$.

Answer (score 1):

Your differential equation is

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{7 x y}{(\ln y)^{8}}$$

which on solving gives  $$y=(\frac{(63x)^2}{2}+C)^{\frac{1}{9}}$$

Now it is given that graph of the above expression passes through thee point  $(0,e)$, Therefore the coordinates should satisfy the equation of graph , doing which gives

$$e=(\frac{(63.0)^2}{2}+C)^{\frac{1}{9}}\implies C=e^9$$

Now we plug $C=e^9$ in the the equation which gives final answer

$$y=(\frac{(63x)^2}{2}+e^9)^{\frac{1}{9}}\implies 9\ln y=\ln(\frac{(63x)^2}{2}+e^9)$$